# What USB Type B connector has screw thread?

Tags: usb, audio, microphone, connector

I have seen multiple devices (all microphones) with a Type B USB connector with screw-thread around it.

- What is this connector/cable called?
- What is it for? (other than securely fastening cables?)
- Are cables with these connectors 'twice-shielded'?
- What devices might have a female USB port with this kind of thread-fastener?

[image: Picture of USB connector of the bottom side of a USB microphone.]
Photo courtesy of [Thomann.de](https://www.thomann.de/intl/cad_audio_u29.htm)

Comment: They are clearly specialist cables. Why don't you ask Thomman?

Comment: I think that is actually a screw mount for a microphone (for a stand). I don’t think the mounts interfere with cables (they are hollow in the middle)

Comment: @singalongconflict - now you mention it,  it's actually remarkably similar to a Neumann mic mount, though as a Neumann mount is about 10x the price of this mic, I think it's an affectation.

Comment: @singalongconflict - actually, yes, you're probably right. I actually had to go grab a Neumann & screw-mount out of the mic cupboard  to check. Only been using them 40 years … obviously without ever actually looking carefully at one. Go ahead & put that in as an answer. Question was a red herring & I fell for it. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Ah, here you go… a £266 shock mount for your £30 mic ;-))) https://www.thomann.de/gb/neumann_ea87.htm

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm just about crazy enough to do it. Say, what are those mounts called? I bet that screw mounting is standardized!

Comment: The mount is very probably standardised - the springing, however, needs to be right for the weight of the mic in the basket mount, otherwise it's just 'decoration'. My Neumann is the only mic I have that has a basket mount option & it came with the mic, so I've simply never thought about it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threads are for a screw mount (to attach the mic to a mic stand). Typically, the screw mount are hollow in the centre (to allow the USB cable to pass through it). To answer your question, the mic in the picture seems to take a typical USB B cable which passes through the mount (so it does not require a special kind of USB B connector).

As an aside, it's usually pretty hard to replace screw mounts (at least the one mic I had had a screw mount that was specific that mic). If you lost the screw mount, you may be able to buy a shock mount [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H40VBVQ). These kinds of mounts grip the sides of the mic instead of attaching to the base (which screw mounts do). Before buying one, be sure that there's no controls or anything on the side of the mic that would get in the way of the mount. You'll also want to ensure your mic's diameter is suitable for whichever mount you pick.

Comment: That's what confused me, I figured all mics like that required a pinching shock mount as that's all I've ever seen. I've never even heard of screw-on shock mounts like @Tetsujin (and you) suggested. Thanks!

Comment: See, I was thinking it was something like [this D-format cat6e cable](https://www.thomann.de/intl/pro_snake_cat6e_cable_20m.htm).